# Beginner in Laravel - Eager loading seems to not work?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to make a post where the user's post can receive likes from other users. But I'm trouble at when you click the user, it was suppose to direct to the users page where you can see all its post and the likes the it received. This is the code that suppose to do that work:

This is the controller:

```
 public function index(User $user)
  { 

    $posts = $user->posts()->with('user', 'likes')->get();

    return view('users.posts.index', [
        'user' => $user,
        'posts' => $posts,
        ]);
        
  }
 }
```

and this is the view/template:

```
 <div class="flex justify-center">
    <div class="w-8/12 bg-white p-6 rounded-lg">

        {{$user->name}}

    </div>
 </div>
```

I don't know what's the problem though, or is it a bug with Laravel eager loading?

But unfortunately it only returns a blank page, there's no error though.
The thing is after putting this code inside dump and die, there's data showing from the database. I don't why it doesn't show. Can someone help me with this problem? Much appreciated

Following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFh0Fd7BsjE

Tutorial Github: https://github.com/codecourse/posty-traversy-media

Comment: Can you show the model and controller as well?

Comment: why would you eager load user when you already have the $user instance

Comment: "I don't why it doesn't show" ... doesn't show what? there is nothing to do any "showing" here

Comment: @sumitwadhwa what I'm trying to do is for when you click the user you will be redirected to the page containing the post and likes of a particular user. I'm only following a tutorial and it seems to not work on my end.

Comment: What does your model contain? Do you have relations in there, etc..

Comment: @lagbox Im sorry. I tried to ask another question prior to the one you already answered earlier. The results still the same. It still doesn't show the Post of the user on the redirected page. Thank you

Comment: why would it? there is nothing here to show a post in a view ... the only thing you are "attempting" to "display" is the user's name

Comment: @lagbox Yes sir. I'm only following a tutorial to make this app. That's why I'm confused on why the result is not the same on mine when I did exactly the same as the tutorial.

Comment: either go through it again or stop using it ...  if you can't follow it or it is wrong you should not be using it as it will be way too confusing to figure out why things aren't working `;)`

Comment: @lagbox Thank you sir. I'm actually doing it for my class project. I didn't know. Thank you for your time sir

Comment: you might as well link to the tutorial you are using

Comment: @lagbox This is the link sir https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFh0Fd7BsjE&t=7378s Thank you again for your time. I really appreciated your thoughts

Comment: https://github.com/codecourse/posty-traversy-media/blob/master/resources/views/users/posts/index.blade.php    that is the final version of that view from the tutorial ... so either you missed something or you haven't completed this yet by this point in the tutorial

Comment: @lagbox copy that sir. I really appreciated your help.  I think I'll just go through it again. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the posts you can iterate through them:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
    {{ $post->likes->count() }}
@endforeach
```

Not sure what data or relationships you want to access.

Answer (score 0):

Check your route whether it has a user id for model injection
eg:/index/{user}
also in your blade example, there is no posts are used.you are using the user object

```
public function index(User $user)
{ 

    $posts = $user->posts()->with('user', 'likes')->get();

    return view('users.posts.index')->with([
        'user' => $user,
        'posts' => $posts,
        ]);
        
 }
```